# Android Browser with Phonegap and jQuery mobile

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a strange problem. I'm developing an Android app with Phonegap and jQuery Mobile.
The issue is this. I have two pages, pageA and pageB... In page A for example I have this:

```
<div  id="Menu" data-role="navbar">
   <a href="pageB.htm" onclick="DoSomeThink()" >Page</a></li>
</div><!-- /navbar -->
```

In PageB I have a script loaded in a JS file. When the page is loaded there is this event:

```
$('.ClassPageB').live('pageshow', function(event, ui) {
  \\Some code here
});
```

If I deploy this on Android phones everything is ok... But if I deploy on tablets the 
live.(pageshow event...) is not performed.

The only way I could resolve the problem is to put in a tag `target="_self"` in the link like this:

```
<a href="pageB.htm" onclick="DoSomeThink()" target="_self" >Page</a></li>
```

But if I use this I loose transition effects of JQmobile...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the JS file containing:

```
$('.ClassPageB').live('pageshow', function(event, ui) {
  \\Some code here
});
```

in **BOTH** `PageA` and `PageB`.

Let me know if this works for you.